# Facebook Questions API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has officially launched its Facebook Questions. Does anyone know if it's possible to add one of the new Facebook "Question" polls through the Graph API? If so, how?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is not available yet. http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=74595

Comment: They just announced the ability to do this.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They just announced this is available on their [blog.](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/590/) To get them, issue an HTTP GET request to the USER_ID/questions endpoint with the user_questions or friends_questions permissions.

Update: they also just [announced](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/) that you can create questions now via the API.

Answer (score 2):

I've searched the http://developer.facebook.com page for poll related search terms and also online.  This yielded no notable results.

It's probably worth making a poll with an external website, most I'm sure are compatible with the Open Graph but will not provide the Facebook interface that you expect on Facebook itself.

Answer (score 0):

This has been deprecated as of Grpah 1.0 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/question